# Forms Runtime parameters

Tags: oracle

I'm working with Oracle Forms Builder 6i. Every time I run a form using "Run Form -> Client/Server" I got user/password prompt. 
Is there any way to set it up so I don't have to type that credentials?

Thx for any help:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your own code in an `ON-LOGON` trigger to login for you:

```
LOGON('USER','PASSWORD' || '@' || 'SID');
```

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Forms_FAQ#Can_one_bypass_the_Oracle_login_screen.3F

This has the benefit that your users won't need to know the database account password. However, this does mean that you now must work out how to securely authenticate your users (e.g. using a custom authentication).